# Bash: Escaping @ in string value in non-associative array

Tags: bash

I am writing a sanitation script to loop through a list of allowed key names to match variables. The variables are email addresses using '@' in the name. I am having a tough time trying to escape out the '@' symbol so that bash isn't trying to use it as a reference point. Could someone help me out. I am probably missing something simple.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

george="cluster2-msid2@somedomain.com"
mike="cluster1-msid@somedomain.com"
john="cluster5-msid3@somedomain.com"

people_key_names=( "george" "mike" "john" )
master_key_values=( "cluster1-msid@somedomain.com" 'cluster2-msid2\@somedomain.com' "cluster5-msid3`@`somedomain.com")

function print_emails(){
    for person in ${people_key_names[@]}; do
        value=$(echo "${!master_key_values["${person}"]}")
        echo "$value"
    done
}

print_emails;
```

Error message being received:

```
./example.sh: line 12: cluster2-msid2@somedomain.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@somedomain.com")

./example.sh: line 12: cluster1-msid@somedomain.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@somedomain.com")

./example.sh: line 12: cluster5-msid3@somedomain.com: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "@somedomain.com")
```

From the answer, the updated code for what I was actually intending once mistake was realized:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

george="cluster2-msid2@somedomain.com"
mike="cluster1-msid@somedomain.com"
john="cluster5-msid3@somedomain.com"

people_key_names=( "george" "mike" "john" )
master_key_values=( "cluster1-msid@somedomain.com" 'cluster2-msid2\@somedomain.com' "cluster5-msid3`@`somedomain.com")

function print_emails(){
    people_success=0
    for key_value in ${master_key_values[@]}; do
        for person_value in ${people_key_names[@]}; do
            echo "Key_Value: $key_value / $person_value : Declared_variable: ${!person_value}"
        done
    done
}

print_emails;
```

Comment: ? So what do you expect `master_key_values["${person}"]}`  to do? If you want to find array index that has a specific value, you have to do exactly that - for each element in array, check if it has that value, if it has, return the index. It's not an index in an array, it's a value of in the array.

Comment: Yeah...egg on my face. I was working too much with associative arrays and completely confused myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 numerically index arrays. To iterate over them, we loop over the *indices* of one of them:

```bash
    for idx in "${!people_key_names[@]}"; do
        echo "person ${person[idx]} has value ${master_key_values[idx]}"
    done
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I completely confused myself. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using associative array?

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr
arr[george]="cluster2-msid2@somedomain.com"
arr[mike]="cluster1-msid@somedomain.com"
arr[john]="cluster5-msid3@somedomain.com"
declare -p arr


for key in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "key: $key ==> value: ${arr[$key]}"; done
```

output

```
declare -A arr=([john]="cluster5-msid3@somedomain.com" [mike]="cluster1-msid@somedomain.com" [george]="cluster2-msid2@somedomain.com" )

key: john ==> value: cluster5-msid3@somedomain.com
key: mike ==> value: cluster1-msid@somedomain.com
key: george ==> value: cluster2-msid2@somedomain.com
```

Another approach

```
declare -A master_key_values=(
        [george,id]=1
        [george,mail]="cluster1-msid@somedomain.com"
        [george,city]="muenster"
        [mike,id]=2
        [mike,mail]="cluster2-msid2@somedomain.com"
        [mike,city]="dortmund"
        [john,id]=3
        [john,mail]="cluster5-msid3@somedomain.com"
        [john,city]="hannover"
)

names=($(for key in "${!master_key_values[@]}"; do echo ${key/,*/};done|sort -u))
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    printf "User %s from %s has id %s and mail %s\n" \
           $name \
           ${master_key_values[$name,city]} \
           ${master_key_values[$name,id]} \
           ${master_key_values[$name,mail]}
done

User george from muenster has id 1 and mail cluster1-msid@somedomain.com
User john from hannover has id 3 and mail cluster5-msid3@somedomain.com
User mike from dortmund has id 2 and mail cluster2-msid2@somedomain.com
```

Comment: In the actual script that I am building, i am already looping through an associative array of key/value pairs and pointing the values to match against a whitelist of allowed values. Since bash can only allow for one level deep (without a hacky workaround), the whitelist needed to be non-associative. (hence where I confused myself in the initial question). Normal easy circumstances, I would totally do it that way.